# Rename tag [standard-sql]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

It seems that the [standard-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standard-sql) is only used to denote the query dialect "Standard SQL" used by Google's BigQuery database engine. I have updated the tag info to reflect that. But in my experience the tag info is rarely read by the people posting a question.

So I would like to suggest to rename `[standard-sql]` to `[bigquery-standard-sql]` or `[google-bigquery-standard-sql]` or something along those lines, to make it clear that this is not about the SQL standard.

I am not suggesting a tag synonym, but a complete rename of the tag.

Comment: There are 11 questions to be manually retagged before the tag can be renamed. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bstandard-sql%5D+-%5Bgoogle-bigquery%5D+is%3Aq+-%22google%22+-%22bigquery%22&mixed=0

Comment: @BhargavRao: thanks for the query. I re-tagged the questions

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I renamed the tag. (First rename that I did on phone).